# I want to get the exact current location using python preferably OFFLINE

Tags: python, location

I want to get the exact current location using python preferably OFFLINE  even if it's lat and long I am ok with it coz you can use reverse_geocoder and if it's ONLINE i would prefer accurate and free API s also if provided with code would be thankful

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It is a specific problem